# as.Date returns NA if applied to a list

Tags: r, as.date

I have want R to recognize this list:

```
 [1] "Ago12" "Ago13" "Ago14" "Ago15" "Ago16" "Ago17" "Ago18"
 [8] "Apr12" "Apr13" "Apr14" "Apr15" "Apr16" "Apr17" "Apr18"
[15] "Apr19" "Dic12" "Dic13" "Dic14" "Dic15" "Dic16" "Dic17"
[22] "Dic18" "Feb12" "Feb13" "Feb14" "Feb15" "Feb16" "Feb17"
[29] "Feb18" "Feb19" "Gen12" "Gen13" "Gen14" "Gen15" "Gen16"
[36] "Gen17" "Gen18" "Gen19" "Giu12" "Giu13" "Giu14" "Giu15"
[43] "Giu16" "Giu17" "Giu18" "Giu19" "Lug12" "Lug13" "Lug14"
[50] "Lug15" "Lug16" "Lug17" "Lug18" "Lug19" "Mag12" "Mag13"
[57] "Mag14" "Mag15" "Mag16" "Mag17" "Mag18" "Mag19" "Mar12"
[64] "Mar13" "Mar14" "Mar15" "Mar16" "Mar17" "Mar18" "Mar19"
[71] "Nov12" "Nov13" "Nov14" "Nov15" "Nov16" "Nov17" "Nov18"
[78] "Ott12" "Ott13" "Ott14" "Ott15" "Ott16" "Ott17" "Ott18"
[85] "Set12" "Set13" "Set14" "Set15" "Set16" "Set17" "Set18"
```

as a Date vector to use it to plot some series. When I run

`time<-as.Date(datecorr,format="%b%y")` I get NAs. 
I also tried to change the system language and time with
`Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME","it_IT.UTF-8")`
, but still it doesn't work.

I wonder what's wrong in what I'm doing

Thanks for help!

Edit: Thank you guys it works well

Comment: You need a day too `as.Date(paste0(datecorr, "01"),format="%b%y%d")` or with `zoo` `as.Date(as.yearmon(datecorr, "%b%y"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the input shown reproducibly in the Note at the end set the locale and then use `as.yearmon` and `as.Date` with the indicated format string. You could consider omitting the `as.Date` part since it is really a year/month you are trying to represent.  `scale_x_yearmon()` can be used with ggplot2.

```
library(zoo)
Sys.setlocale(locale = "Italian")
as.Date(as.yearmon(x, format = "%b%y"))
```

giving:

```
 [1] "2012-08-01" "2013-08-01" "2014-08-01" "2015-08-01" "2016-08-01"
 [6] "2017-08-01" "2018-08-01" "2012-04-01" "2013-04-01" "2014-04-01"
[11] "2015-04-01" "2016-04-01" "2017-04-01" "2018-04-01" "2019-04-01"
[16] "2012-12-01" "2013-12-01" "2014-12-01" "2015-12-01" "2016-12-01"
[21] "2017-12-01" "2018-12-01" "2012-02-01" "2013-02-01" "2014-02-01"
[26] "2015-02-01" "2016-02-01" "2017-02-01" "2018-02-01" "2019-02-01"
[31] "2012-01-01" "2013-01-01" "2014-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2016-01-01"
[36] "2017-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2019-01-01" "2012-06-01" "2013-06-01"
[41] "2014-06-01" "2015-06-01" "2016-06-01" "2017-06-01" "2018-06-01"
[46] "2019-06-01" "2012-07-01" "2013-07-01" "2014-07-01" "2015-07-01"
[51] "2016-07-01" "2017-07-01" "2018-07-01" "2019-07-01" "2012-05-01"
[56] "2013-05-01" "2014-05-01" "2015-05-01" "2016-05-01" "2017-05-01"
[61] "2018-05-01" "2019-05-01" "2012-03-01" "2013-03-01" "2014-03-01"
[66] "2015-03-01" "2016-03-01" "2017-03-01" "2018-03-01" "2019-03-01"
[71] "2012-11-01" "2013-11-01" "2014-11-01" "2015-11-01" "2016-11-01"
[76] "2017-11-01" "2018-11-01" "2012-10-01" "2013-10-01" "2014-10-01"
[81] "2015-10-01" "2016-10-01" "2017-10-01" "2018-10-01" "2012-09-01"
[86] "2013-09-01" "2014-09-01" "2015-09-01" "2016-09-01" "2017-09-01"
[91] "2018-09-01"
```

### Note

```
 Lines <- '"Ago12" "Ago13" "Ago14" "Ago15" "Ago16" "Ago17" "Ago18"
 "Apr12" "Apr13" "Apr14" "Apr15" "Apr16" "Apr17" "Apr18"
 "Apr19" "Dic12" "Dic13" "Dic14" "Dic15" "Dic16" "Dic17"
 "Dic18" "Feb12" "Feb13" "Feb14" "Feb15" "Feb16" "Feb17"
 "Feb18" "Feb19" "Gen12" "Gen13" "Gen14" "Gen15" "Gen16"
 "Gen17" "Gen18" "Gen19" "Giu12" "Giu13" "Giu14" "Giu15"
 "Giu16" "Giu17" "Giu18" "Giu19" "Lug12" "Lug13" "Lug14"
 "Lug15" "Lug16" "Lug17" "Lug18" "Lug19" "Mag12" "Mag13"
 "Mag14" "Mag15" "Mag16" "Mag17" "Mag18" "Mag19" "Mar12"
 "Mar13" "Mar14" "Mar15" "Mar16" "Mar17" "Mar18" "Mar19"
 "Nov12" "Nov13" "Nov14" "Nov15" "Nov16" "Nov17" "Nov18"
 "Ott12" "Ott13" "Ott14" "Ott15" "Ott16" "Ott17" "Ott18"
 "Set12" "Set13" "Set14" "Set15" "Set16" "Set17" "Set18"'
x <- scan(text = Lines, what = "", quiet = TRUE)
```

Comment: I think the OP intends the numbers to be years, not dates, judging by the format "%b%y" they tried

Comment: Have modified accordingly.